# Text Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, text, indexing

i have a table with approximately million rows holding a text  500-600 words and i'm searching word within these texts. but iterating rows and searching within the text is not efficient from time aspect. any idea?

Comment: What method are you using to store the table data? flat file? MySQL? It's a rather critical piece of information for your question

Comment: mssql varchar(max) in table but i can change storage method. c#, mssql i'm using.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Lucene

http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Answer (score 2):

With this scarce information, I suggest you have a look at [inverted indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). Easy to build up and fast retrieval for your case, as far as I can tell. Also very easy to implement in any kind of database environment in case you cannot switch to a database which already supports them.

If you give more information maybe another solution would also work.

Comment: but i'm also using levenshtein method(edit_distance) for looking if how much the two words( user entered word and  the next word in database text) are similar.  how can we use inverted index and levenshtein in the same method. i'm thinking about it. because if the 'cat' is not found in the texts, i want to give response maybe you are searching 'hat' there is such text which includes 'hat' or the user entered quute, the response ' i think you are looking for "quite"'.

Comment: If you want to use both inverted indexes and levensthein, you can implement inverted indexes within a trie. Tries support Levensthein lookup if you do it correctly. Each leaf then would contain a list of all the matched documents. Please give more detailed information next time in the question to allow other to find a good answer directly.